# Linux Application glibc Stack Trace

Tags: gdb, glibc

My program is crashing with below stack trace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xffffe430 in ?? ()
#1  0xf73a1765 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xf73e4da3 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0xf73e989c in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0xf5fc6935 in MemoryFree (block=0x25757) at ../demo/demolib.c:536
.
.
.
```

In the frame 4 free() function is getting called and I know the error and solution.

Problem is in the above stack trace the frames 0 to 3 does not display any function names and just shows library libc.so.6. At frame 3 probably free() will be called.

I wanted to know how to get the libc.so.6 function names displayed in the stack trace?

Comment: Try running it under valgrind, it may provide useful information about the crash.

Comment: problem is the application does not core usually.
It cored once at some ones system I have a core the stack trace of which is above.
So in the core stack trace I want to see the glibc functions called.

Comment: It doesn't have to crash (and coredump). valgrind lets you detect certain types of memory access that are made by error. If your program crashes due to memory violation it will be detected by valgrind. It may provide you with clues to what the error is even if the program doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how to get the libc.so.6 function names displayed in the stack trace?

That usually happens automatically. The reason it doesn't happen for you is most likely that you've turned `auto-solib-add off` in your `~/.gdbinit`.

Don't do that, or use `sharedlibrary .` to load symbols for all shared libraries at the crash point.